kube-proxy errors and quits with nf_conntrack_max: no such file
I am getting the following error when I run microk8s on ubuntu 22 server LTS.  Just a default install of 22 and microk8s with all default options.
Apr 10 07:21:28 k8s-master microk8s.daemon-kubelite[13219]: E0410 07:21:28.994248   13219 server.go:537] "Error running ProxyServer" err="open /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: no such file or directory"
Apr 10 07:21:28 k8s-master microk8s.daemon-kubelite[13219]: Error: open /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max: no such file or directory

So nf_conntrack_max sometimes disappears randomly on boot.  How come nf_conntrack is required but not loaded by minik8s or parent services?

See this issue on the github - link: https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/4449

I was able to solve this temporarily with modprobe nf_conntrack.
You can make that permanent by editing /etc/modules, adding nf_conntrack so the kernel module always loads on boot.
Related github issue: https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/4449
